# 2 level nested form with acts_as_commentable and nested_form gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, nested-forms, acts-as-commentable

I am using [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) and [acts_as_commentable](https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable)

I want to be able to add comments to either a Question or a Solution.  A Question has many Solutions (think stackoverflow and you won't be far wrong).

For the nested form below how do I pass Solution.comments to the link_to_add helper (see #comment 4th line from end)?  Currently comments entered below specific Solutions are assigned to the parent Question (on submit), even though the helper is embedded in the fields_for of the Solution fields.

(**NOTE**: if I add comments via Solution.comments.create in the rails console the comment is displayed correctly under the solution when I redisplay so I am pretty sure that it is just the link_to_add helper call that I need to fix.

Anyone got any ideas?

Here is the (haml) nested form

```
= nested_form_for @question, :html => { :class => 'form' } do |f|
  .control-group
    = f.fields_for :comments do |comment_form|
      = comment_form.text_field :comment
      = comment_form.link_to_remove "Remove Comment"
    %p= f.link_to_add "Add a comment", :comments
  .form-actions
    = f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary'
  .control-group
    = f.fields_for :solutions do |solution_form|
      = solution_form.text_area :solution
      = solution_form.link_to_remove "Remove Solution"
      %br
      = solution_form.fields_for :comments do |comments_form|
        = comments_form.text_field :comment
        = comments_form.link_to_remove "Remove Comment"
      # I believe the below line is the problem
      %p= solution_form.link_to_add "Add Comment", :comments
    %p= f.link_to_add "Add Solution", :solutions
  .form-actions
    = f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary'
```